# How to open a unix terminal text editor from Java via Runtime.getRuntime().exec()?

Tags: java, emacs

I'm trying to open a specific file with the emacs editor from my console-based java program by doing the following:

```
int exitValue = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands).waitFor();
```

Where *commands* is a String array of two elements:

```
commands[0] = "emacs";
commands[1] = "/home/test.txt"; // The actual path I'm using is different.
```

So, when I run this, emacs doesn't open, but instead my program continues to run, and in the exitValue I get *1* after the line above (first one) executes. What am I doing wrong?

Also, if I try using either *vi* or *nano* for the same purpose, instead of continuing running the program just hangs there after executing that line, but neither editor actually opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process is probably emitting a message on its standard error.  Reading standard error requires invoking the [getErrorStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream--) method of the Process object, and reading from the returned InputStream in a separate Thread.

Sounds rather involved, doesn’t it?  That is one of the reasons Runtime.exec was replaced years ago by [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), which makes viewing of a Process’s output much easier:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("emacs", "/home/test.txt");

// Makes Process use Java program’s stdin, stdout and stderr.
builder.inheritIO();

int exitValue = builder.start().waitFor();
```

That won’t make your command work, but it will allow you to see what’s going wrong.

Comment: This does what exactly what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple: leave out the xterm, just start vi:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("vi", "/home/test.txt").start();
```

If you want more command line arguments for vi, add them as separate strings, not inside the "" of first argument.

And launching a terminal program like vi naturally requires, that you started the java app from visible terminal, so vi has a terminal to use, but I assume this is so.

Comment: I’m actually not sure if you’re trolling or not, by suggesting Joe should just use vi instead of emacs…

Comment: This doesn't make a difference. It behaves exactly the same way as before. If I use vi, it just hangs there after executing this line, if I use emacs, it doesn't really do anything, but just moves on to the next code.